# in a Rails apps, how to organize Cucumber .feature files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, cucumber

when i got to this project there were cucumber tests in "features/enhanced", which ran with javascript and a few in "features/plain" which did not require js. with the later development of per-scenario @javascript, this doesn't make sense. and as the number of features files we have grows and grows, it'd be awesome if this stayed tidy.

so, in best practice land:

1) how long should .feature files be? i try to keep each narrow and specific with 1 or 2 "Scenarios".

2) what folder/file structure should one keep them in?
  2a) how might one group similar features?

Answer (score 2):

1) Once you've done them for a few months you'll soon find what works best for you. My advice is you should make them small ish. We have often split our earlier features down into smaller chunks, but have never ended up combining them. It's handy for making use of backgrounds etc...

2) We had a big problem with this and spent ages doing it one way then another. In the end we gunned to group them by the services that our company provides. e.g. payments, customer registration, stock management

Inconveniently, features don't always conform to a hierarchical tree view of the world, so make liberal use of tagging and your primary grouping of features is less important.

Have you tried yard? There's an example [here](http://recursivegames.com/cukes/) We've just built it into our CI, it lets you pull together sets of scenarios based on tags, you can do unions, intersections etc... well worth it :)

Comment: great, thanks. i'm always tempted to cling to some "controller" based organization. i agree that this breaks down with "features".

Answer (score 1):

I would keep the JavaScript and non-JavaScript versions of a scenario together, since they should be very similar.

Anything more than 8 scenarios in a feature file is probably too much.

A useful approach is to have a folder to represent the high-levels features (sometimes call epics or themes), and separate feature files within those folders for the different **aspects** of the behaviour.

For example, you may have a feature "Employee Directory" which would have separate feature files contains scenarios for a photograph, office location, job title, etc.

Depending on the size and complexity of your app, you could group those folders into other folders.

(Note that none of the above is specific to Rails apps).

Comment: thanks, yea, the separation of js/non-js stemmed from some early implementation, i'll be glad to toss it. more folders!